# How can I use a SET variable concisely in a DROP/CREATE/INSERT statements in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a template of a migration script that we run with new version when needed. It's something like:

```
SET "myapp.user"='someuser'; --This line CANNOT change

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS backup_tables.someuser_parameter;
CREATE TABLE backup_tables.someuser_parameter AS SELECT * FROM "public".parameter;

INSERT INTO "public".parameter (key, value, enabled)
    SELECT
        'task_name',
        (
            '{"worker_config": {"crontab": {"hour": "0", "minute": "1"}, "disabled": false, "periodic_task": true, "username": "' || current_setting('myapp.user') || '"}}'
        )::JSONB,
    TRUE;
```

As you can see, the *myapp.user* value (someuser) is used at three places in the script.

1. Is there a more elegant way to use *myapp.user* in the INSERT?
2. How can I use myapp.user in the DROP TABLE and the CREATE TABLE statements?

I use PostgreSQL 9.4.14 if it changes something.

Comment: You will need an anonymous pl/pgsql block and dynamic SQL for the DDL commands. I.e. something like `execute format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS backup_tables.%I', current_setting('myapp.user'));` You can assign `current_setting('myapp.user')` to a text variable in the pl/pgsql block and this may make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SET "myapp.user"='someuser'; --This line CANNOT change

do language plpgsql
$$
declare
  myapp_user text := current_setting('myapp.user');
begin
  execute format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS backup_tables.%I', myapp_user);
  execute format('CREATE TABLE backup_tables.%I AS SELECT * FROM "public".parameter', myapp_user);

  INSERT INTO "public".parameter (key, value, enabled)
    SELECT
        'task_name',
        (
            '{"worker_config": {"crontab": {"hour": "0", "minute": "1"}, "disabled": false, "periodic_task": true, "username": "' || myapp_user || '"}}'
        )::JSONB,
        TRUE;
end;
$$;
```